# Как передать {{ }} в {% %}?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-template

```py
def iq(request):
    data={
        "image": "main/img/fff.png"
    }
    return render(request, 'main/iq1.html', data)
```

```html
<img src="{% static {{ image }} %}" alt="Лого">
```

Как передать `{{ }}` в `{% %}`?

Comment: Просто `{% static image %}`

Comment: img src="{{ data.image }}"